# datagridview cellclick event works like cellcontentclick

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am a newbiew in c# and visual studio, and I am planning in developing a inventory system using the datagridview. When I was testing it and using the cellclick event, it worked like the cellcontentclick event, which I have to click the content to make sure it is the clicking is read by the app, any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [faq] and [ask] before asking a question..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the cellclick event is much better over the cellcontentclick. If you only have text inside the cells, you'll most likely have significant blank space that will not trigger the event if you are using the cellcontentclick. That would create a confusing user experience if the event triggers only when the text is clicked.

Only use the cellcontentclick if you have a specific reason for using it, and for 99% of the time, you should be using cellclick.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's why I got a problem, I have used the cellclick event but it is not working as expected. I pop up a message everytime the cell is clicked but the message only popped up after I clicked the text. Is this a bug?

Comment: So you know for later, that information should have been part of your original question. Are you sure that the cellclick event you have is wired up to the cellclick event on the form? In the Designer, you can have any method as any event, so just because you named it cellclickevent doesn't guarantee that it is being fired on the cellclick event. Any code you could provide would be very helpful.

Comment: yes i got a mistake in the form, such a silly mistake :( Thanks much btw